# Windows Phone 8.1 Map AuthenticationToken

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I got a question about where do I need to get my AuthenticationToken for the Map services on WP8 (and 8.1). I'm using the following namespace for my map

```
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
```

and this map

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map"> ... </maps:Map>
```

When I now run the app in the simulator I get a nice red message "Warning: No authentication ID and/or token specified". When I run the app in my test device no message is shown at all.

My question is the following, where do I get the ID and token? Because I found the following and it's getting me all confused.

Option 1:
On the [www.bingmapsportal](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/) website I made a free account and token. But they don't give me any ID only a token. And since I don't see any references in my code to Bing I think this is a wrong key :)

Option 2:
I found this post on MSDN [How to add a Map control to a page in Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj207033(v=vs.105).aspx). If you scroll down to "Adding the ApplicationID and AuthenticationToken" there is another way to create a token and ID for the map. But it seems I need a dev account for that :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to generate it directly inside the Windows Store App portal, see the procedure here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207033(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_appidandtoken

Comment: Thanks mate! You got an idea why there is the BingMapsPortal then?

Comment: Bing Maps portal is for Bing Maps and Bing Maps for Enterprise customers and users, the WP8 Map control is providing by Here which is a different provider.
So the Bing Maps portal is for a different platform that provides various services.